# Automatically copying doxygen comments from source to headers (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

An advantage of having doxygen comments in the source is that the comments are authored close to the code (and are therefore more readily updated, generally resulting in better doxygen comments on continuously updated projects).

An advantage of having doxygen comments in the header files is that IDE's can present that header information to users as they operate the code (e.g. in a library where you include the headers, but the source is already compiled to a static/dynamic library).

Q) Is there a clean method for automatically copying the doxygen comments from source files to header files (e.g. on a build install script)?

for reference : https://github.com/quixdb/squash/issues/189#issuecomment-183196660

Comment: Isn't doxygen doing this "sort of" automatically?

Comment: IDEs can't pick up doxygen comments in the source files of code they aren't compiling; see the second paragraph of the question, and https://github.com/quixdb/squash/issues/189#issuecomment-181721221 for some screenshots showing the difference in VS.

Comment: Do you mean copy the source file contents to the .h file?  If want your .h and .c/cpp files to match, I use a file compare like Beyond Compare.

Comment: no. the code implementations should stay in the cpp file. only the doxygen comments should be copied across, and only as a 'publish' process when releasing libraries without the source (i.e. headers and libs)